# is not a field of struct type hugolib.SiteInfo in

Tags: hugo, toml

I tried adding a new property to my `theme/partials/footer.html` template, and adding that property to my `/config.toml` file, but I keep getting the error:

`ERROR: 2017/07/09 template: theme/partials/footer.html:16:40: executing "theme/partials/footer.html" at <.Site.CopyrightStart...>: CopyrightStartYear is not a field of struct type *hugolib.SiteInfo in theme/partials/footer.html`

Example from my partial template file:

```
<span>&copy; {{.Site.copyrightStartYear}}</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template engine in Hugo will look for all site params under the `[Params]` block in the `config.toml` file (must be a quoted string for this example). These can be referenced via the `.Site.Params.<paramName>` lookup in partial templates.

e.g.

```
# config.toml
...
[Params]
    myParam = "weeee!"
...
```

And use it in your HTML fragment:

```
# somePartial.html
<span>{{ .Site.Params.myParam }}</span>
...
```